# Radbutton setting visible from javascript

Tags: jquery, telerik

The below statement cannot be done.

```
$find("<%=RadButtonStackoveflow.ClientID%>").visible(false);
```

But are there any way to make visible false of a Radbutton from javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var radButton = $find("<%= RadButtonStackoveflow.ClientID %>");
radButton.set_visible(false);
```

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-client-side-basics.html when I look at this page, there is no property like set_visible??
thanks for quick reply..

Comment: That's how I hide my Rad button in my application.. Are you facing any issues?

Comment: Ok here you go : http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/button/show-hide-radbutton-from-client.aspx . The link to what i was saying.. Its on the official Telerik forums. They have confirmed that it is not yet in the documentation and are working to get it in there

Comment: thank you Rutwik Reddy, you are right. and it works. thank you. the documentation is not full filled..